# Matlab-latex or latex-mathematica for matrices with symbolic elements and involving some calculus?

Tags: matrices, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I'm working on some matrices involving symbolic expressions and calculus as well, should I start typing these matrices in Matlab and do the calculus and all the calculations in Matlab, and then use the Latex command to transfer the results to Latex, or should I start by typing all  the matrices in Latex and copy those to Mathematica (I'm thinking of wolfram online) I heard that it can take Latex command, which way do you think guys in more efficient.

Comment: Without knowing which calculations you need to carry out, it's hard to give specific advice. Have you tried one or the other approach you've outlined? Have you experienced any difficulties? Is mathematica giving you any trouble one way or the other?

Comment: Calculus and basic matrix algebra. I want to know which one powerful, thus I'll consider. I used to work on Matlab, and didn't try mathematica anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a real expert in this area but I give it a try.

I don't think that it is important wheter you use *Matlab* or *Mathematica* - they are both professional tools.

When you say *Matlab* I think that you mean the *Matlab* toolbox *MuPad* which is used for symbolic math.

> - Use *Matlab* (*MuPad*) or *Mathematica* for the math.
> - Use an export-2-LaTeX feature of those tools in order to typeset the stuff. At least it minimizes the manual work - you might have to
>     visually/syntactic optimize the code.

Here are screenshots of my (German) LaTeX tutorial showing examples. The slides are from 2011 anbd therefore probably *not* up to date!

[image]

[image]