# What symbolic math software can output latex quickly?

Tags: math-mode

Many times when I am using a symbolic computation tool (like Maple), I want to take the calculation/ and or the results and have them formatted into LaTex.

> Is there a specific piece of software that does symbolic computing (Maple, MatLab, Mathematica...) and also allows you to quickly copy your work and paste it as math mode Latex or export a clean LaTex file?

For example I have used the `export as latex` option in the past for Maple, but it includes a lot of code just to display other elements of the worksheet that I am not interested in. Ideally I would like to avoid reformatting the equations I have written as much as possible.

(Note I have tried **MathSage\SageTex and everything it offers** but the combination of bugs and limited support outside of Linux makes it a problem to use).

Comment: Only slightly related to this: in case you did not know, you can also [export Matlab figures to TikZ](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), where the figures can contain LaTeX formulae.

Comment: `sympy` perhaps, see e.g. http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.latex.latex It is a Python package, and [part of the SciPy stack](http://scipy.org/stackspec.html).

Comment: you don't have to convert the whole maple worksheet you can convert individual expressions eg http://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/courses/math696/converting-Maple-code-into-LaTeX.html

Comment: Even though you say you don't like it, I recommend [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/). Support via https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support is pretty rapid - there's also https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/, but I haven't used this. For what I do I am not aware of any major bugs. (Disclaimer: I have contributed to sage, but I also moved to sage because I didn't like the alternatives.) Another option is [Gap](http://www.gap-system.org/).

Comment: Take a look at the programm sagemath!

Comment: Maybe my answer here helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337746/

Comment: We need more detail here. Can you show how this is done in Sagemath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mathematica, you can use [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html):

```
In[1]:= TrigExpand[Sin[5 x]] // TeXForm

Out[1]//TeXForm=
\sin ^5(x)+5 \sin (x) \cos ^4(x)-10 \sin ^3(x) \cos ^2(x)
```

You can also right click and select Copy As -> LaTeX

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, `sympy` might be an option, see e.g. the docs: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.latex.latex.

It is a Python package, and part of the SciPy stack. Hence it is also available in [Sage MathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/), and probably the desktop version of Sage Math.

An example from a terminal session:

```python
In [1]: import sympy as sp
   ...: from sympy.printing import latex as spl

In [2]: x = sp.symbols('x')

In [3]: f = (1/sp.cos(x))

In [4]: print(spl(f.series(x,0,6)))
1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{5 x^{4}}{24} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{6}\right)
```